# Doxygen auto link in page title

Tags: doxygen

If I use % to suppress an auto link in the page title, the % shows up in the navigation pane as part of the page title in the HTML output. Does anyone have a suggestion, besides removing capital letters from the word?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using.

Comment: Can you see if the same problem still occurs with the current (1.8.7) version? As it might be related to the following bug as mentioned in bugzilla: Bug 674851 - Percent to prevent auto-linking in page title is not removed for navpath (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=674851)